# Can't get QueryDsl / APT to generate Q classes

Tags: spring, maven, querydsl

I'm trying to use QueryDsl in a new Spring project.  I'm new to QueryDsl, and pretty new to maven and Spring, so I may be missing something fairly basic, but I can't get QueryDsl / maven-apt-plugin to generate my Q classes.  The Querydsl reference makes sound so easy; I think I did exactly what it said:

I configured pom.xml with:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-apt-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>process</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/java</outputDirectory>
        <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

and:

```
<repository>
  <id>QUERYDSL</id>
  <url>http://source.mysema.com/maven2/releases</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

and:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have two @Entity's in that project.

mvn clean install does not result in any output to target/generated-sources/java/

What am I missing?

I tried mvn apt:process, and it results in:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.mysema.maven:maven-apt-plugin:1.0.3:process (default-cli) on project logging-implementation: Either processor or processors need to be given -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal com.mysema.maven:maven-apt-plugin:1.0.3:process (default-cli) on project logging-implementation: Either processor or processors need to be given
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

OK, I got it.
I don't understand it (I'm a Maven noob), but here's what worked:
In the parent pom.xml, I have

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins> 
      the maven-apt-plugin definition shown above 
    </plugin>
  <pluginManagement>
</build>
```

and in the project's POM I have:

```
<build>
    <plugins> 
      the **exact same** maven-apt-plugin definition shown above 
    </plugin>
</build>
```

without the <pluginManagement> level betweeen <build> and <plugins>, following the instructions at http://mojo.codehaus.org/apt-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: OK, now I get it.  BTW, it's not necessary to repeat the entire plugin definition in the project POM, just the groupId and artifactId are sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the goal directly, but the configuration is execution specific. So either use apt via the standard maven lifecycle or make the configuration general.

Comment: Timo, shouldn't "mvn clean install" work? Is there some other configuration I need to make?  thanks!

Comment: mvn clean install should work, the build/plugins/plugin part is necessary