# An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I haven't been able to update my maven project for a while.

I've seen many posts about this, but couldn't find a fix.

I get the following error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project". 
org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject
```

The "log" shows:

```
...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2015-04-24 10:57:08.261
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
!STACK 0
java.lang.LinkageError: org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.internal.core.SpringProjectConfigurator.doConfigure(SpringProjectConfigurator.java:42)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.AbstractSpringProjectConfigurator.configure(AbstractSpringProjectConfigurator.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.project.configurator.AbstractLifecycleMapping.configure(AbstractLifecycleMapping.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$3.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:408)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:321)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1344)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

...
```

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

I found an apparently not related bug report [here][1] where Martin Lippert explains how to show all maven "instalations" like this:

> Can you try out: open the console in your Eclipse, select the "Host OSGi console" variant, then type in the command "packages org.apache.maven.project", and then let us know what the output of this is? That could help to find out where this conflict comes from. Thanks a lot in advance!

So, I did it and found two:

```
WARNING: This console is connected to the current running instance of Eclipse!
osgi> packages org.apache.maven.project
osgi.wiring.package; bundle-version:Version="1.5.0.20140605-2032"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime"; osgi.wiring.package="org.apache.maven.project"; version:Version="0.0.0"<org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.5.0.20140605-2032 [588]>
  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven_3.6.4.201503051146-RELEASE [1133] imports
osgi.wiring.package; bundle-version:Version="1.5.1.20150109-1819"; bundle-symbolic-name="org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime"; osgi.wiring.package="org.apache.maven.project"; version:Version="0.0.0"<org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime_1.5.1.20150109-1819 [1188]>
  org.sonatype.m2e.mavenarchiver_0.16.0.201401211452-signed-20140310144306 [893] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1193] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.scm_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1194] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.5.0.20140605-2032 [587] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jaxrs_1.1.0.20140611-1646 [596] imports
  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.properties.editor_3.6.4.201503051146-RELEASE [1125] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1191] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.jdt_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1181] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_1.5.1.20150109-1819 [1175] imports
  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot_3.6.4.201503051146-RELEASE [1123] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.editor_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1179] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa_1.1.0.e43-20140611-1648 [597] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.core_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1176] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1177] imports
  org.springframework.ide.eclipse.roo.ui_3.6.4.201503051146-RELEASE [1200] imports
  org.maven.ide.eclipse.ajdt_0.13.0.201107281640 [884] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jsf_1.1.0.20140611-1646 [598] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common_1.5.0.20140605-2032 [575] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.wtp_1.1.0.20140611-1646 [595] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1192] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.launching_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1183] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer_1.5.1.20150109-1819 [1187] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.discovery_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1178] imports
  org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml_1.5.1.20150109-1820 [1180] imports
osgi>
```

Could anybody tell me if this is ok, or how to remove one of them?

Here is my "configuration":

```
*** Date: Friday, April 24, 2015 at 11:22:22 AM Central Daylight Time

*** Platform Details:

*** System properties:
applicationXMI=org.eclipse.ui.workbench/LegacyIDE.e4xmi
awt.toolkit=sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.branding.ui.isOnlyJiraInstalled=true
eclipse.application=org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
eclipse.buildId=3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE-e44
eclipse.commands=-os
win32
-ws
win32
-arch
x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher
C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\STS.exe
-name
STS
--launcher.library
C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316\eclipse_1608.dll
-startup
C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata
2854_5c
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
-data
C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/javaw.exe
eclipse.home.location=file:/C:/Users/ely/Documents/Desarrollo/Spring/springsource/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/
eclipse.launcher=C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\STS.exe
eclipse.launcher.name=STS
eclipse.p2.data.area=@config.dir/../p2/
eclipse.p2.profile=DefaultProfile
eclipse.product=org.springsource.sts.ide
eclipse.startTime=1429810623199
eclipse.stateSaveDelayInterval=30000
eclipse.vm=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/javaw.exe
eclipse.vmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-XX:MaxPermSize=256M
-jar
C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
equinox.use.ds=true
file.encoding=UTF-8
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
file.separator=\
gosh.args=--nointeractive
guice.disable.misplaced.annotation.check=true
java.awt.graphicsenv=sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
java.awt.printerjob=sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
java.class.path=C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
java.class.version=51.0
java.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\endorsed
java.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
java.home=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre
java.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\ely\AppData\Local\Temp\
java.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\spring-roo-gvNIX-1.2.1-RELEASE\bin;C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\apache-maven-3.1.0\bin;C:\Users\ely\MisProgramas\xampp-portable-win32-1.8.3-beta1-VC11\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\OEM\12.0\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Roxio\OEM\AudioCore\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Roxio Shared\DLLShared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;.
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
java.runtime.version=1.7.0_25-b17
java.specification.name=Java Platform API Specification
java.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.specification.version=1.7
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
java.vendor.url.bug=http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
java.version=1.7.0_25
java.vm.info=mixed mode
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
java.vm.specification.name=Java Virtual Machine Specification
java.vm.specification.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.specification.version=1.7
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vm.version=23.25-b01
javax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all
javax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
line.separator=

org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog
org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpoints.toggleFactoriesUsed=false
org.eclipse.debug.ui.debugViewToolbarVisible=false
org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.splash.location=c:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\org.springsource.sts_3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE\splash.bmp
org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator.configUrl=file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundles.info
org.eclipse.m2e.log.dir=C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration
org.eclipse.update.reconcile=false
org.osgi.framework.executionenvironment=OSGi/Minimum-1.0,OSGi/Minimum-1.1,OSGi/Minimum-1.2,JRE-1.1,J2SE-1.2,J2SE-1.3,J2SE-1.4,J2SE-1.5,JavaSE-1.6,JavaSE-1.7
org.osgi.framework.language=en
org.osgi.framework.os.name=Windows7
org.osgi.framework.os.version=6.1.0
org.osgi.framework.processor=x86-64
org.osgi.framework.system.capabilities=osgi.ee; osgi.ee="OSGi/Minimum"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JRE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1",osgi.ee; osgi.ee="JavaSE"; version:List<Version>="1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7"
org.osgi.framework.system.packages=javax.accessibility,javax.activation,javax.activity,javax.annotation,javax.annotation.processing,javax.crypto,javax.crypto.interfaces,javax.crypto.spec,javax.imageio,javax.imageio.event,javax.imageio.metadata,javax.imageio.plugins.bmp,javax.imageio.plugins.jpeg,javax.imageio.spi,javax.imageio.stream,javax.jws,javax.jws.soap,javax.lang.model,javax.lang.model.element,javax.lang.model.type,javax.lang.model.util,javax.management,javax.management.loading,javax.management.modelmbean,javax.management.monitor,javax.management.openmbean,javax.management.relation,javax.management.remote,javax.management.remote.rmi,javax.management.timer,javax.naming,javax.naming.directory,javax.naming.event,javax.naming.ldap,javax.naming.spi,javax.net,javax.net.ssl,javax.print,javax.print.attribute,javax.print.attribute.standard,javax.print.event,javax.rmi,javax.rmi.CORBA,javax.rmi.ssl,javax.script,javax.security.auth,javax.security.auth.callback,javax.security.auth.kerberos,javax.security.auth.login,javax.security.auth.spi,javax.security.auth.x500,javax.security.cert,javax.security.sasl,javax.sound.midi,javax.sound.midi.spi,javax.sound.sampled,javax.sound.sampled.spi,javax.sql,javax.sql.rowset,javax.sql.rowset.serial,javax.sql.rowset.spi,javax.swing,javax.swing.border,javax.swing.colorchooser,javax.swing.event,javax.swing.filechooser,javax.swing.plaf,javax.swing.plaf.basic,javax.swing.plaf.metal,javax.swing.plaf.multi,javax.swing.plaf.nimbus,javax.swing.plaf.synth,javax.swing.table,javax.swing.text,javax.swing.text.html,javax.swing.text.html.parser,javax.swing.text.rtf,javax.swing.tree,javax.swing.undo,javax.tools,javax.transaction,javax.transaction.xa,javax.xml,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.bind.annotation,javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters,javax.xml.bind.attachment,javax.xml.bind.helpers,javax.xml.bind.util,javax.xml.crypto,javax.xml.crypto.dom,javax.xml.crypto.dsig,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo,javax.xml.crypto.dsig.spec,javax.xml.datatype,javax.xml.namespace,javax.xml.parsers,javax.xml.soap,javax.xml.stream,javax.xml.stream.events,javax.xml.stream.util,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.transform.sax,javax.xml.transform.stax,javax.xml.transform.stream,javax.xml.validation,javax.xml.ws,javax.xml.ws.handler,javax.xml.ws.handler.soap,javax.xml.ws.http,javax.xml.ws.soap,javax.xml.ws.spi,javax.xml.ws.spi.http,javax.xml.ws.wsaddressing,javax.xml.xpath,org.ietf.jgss,org.omg.CORBA,org.omg.CORBA_2_3,org.omg.CORBA_2_3.portable,org.omg.CORBA.DynAnyPackage,org.omg.CORBA.ORBPackage,org.omg.CORBA.portable,org.omg.CORBA.TypeCodePackage,org.omg.CosNaming,org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextExtPackage,org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage,org.omg.Dynamic,org.omg.DynamicAny,org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyFactoryPackage,org.omg.DynamicAny.DynAnyPackage,org.omg.IOP,org.omg.IOP.CodecFactoryPackage,org.omg.IOP.CodecPackage,org.omg.Messaging,org.omg.PortableInterceptor,org.omg.PortableInterceptor.ORBInitInfoPackage,org.omg.PortableServer,org.omg.PortableServer.CurrentPackage,org.omg.PortableServer.POAManagerPackage,org.omg.PortableServer.POAPackage,org.omg.PortableServer.portable,org.omg.PortableServer.ServantLocatorPackage,org.omg.SendingContext,org.omg.stub.java.rmi,org.w3c.dom,org.w3c.dom.bootstrap,org.w3c.dom.css,org.w3c.dom.events,org.w3c.dom.html,org.w3c.dom.ls,org.w3c.dom.ranges,org.w3c.dom.stylesheets,org.w3c.dom.traversal,org.w3c.dom.views,org.w3c.dom.xpath,org.xml.sax,org.xml.sax.ext,org.xml.sax.helpers
org.osgi.framework.uuid=4047775b-dfe9-0014-14b9-d70890841b00
org.osgi.framework.vendor=Eclipse
org.osgi.framework.version=1.8.0
org.osgi.supports.framework.extension=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.fragment=true
org.osgi.supports.framework.requirebundle=true
os.arch=amd64
os.name=Windows 7
os.version=6.1
osgi.arch=x86_64
osgi.bundles=reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.fx.osgi_1.2.0.201501301028.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.1.0.v20131217-1203.jar@1:start
osgi.bundles.defaultStartLevel=4
osgi.compatibility.bootdelegation=true
osgi.configuration.area=file:/C:/Users/ely/Documents/Desarrollo/Spring/springsource/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/configuration/
osgi.framework=file:/c:/Users/ely/Documents/Desarrollo/Spring/springsource/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.2.v20150203-1939.jar
osgi.framework.extensions=reference:file:org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar,reference:file:org.eclipse.fx.osgi_1.2.0.201501301028.jar
osgi.framework.shape=jar
osgi.framework.useSystemProperties=true
osgi.frameworkClassPath=., file:c:/Users/ely/Documents/Desarrollo/Spring/springsource/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.hook_1.1.100.weaving-hook-20140821.jar, file:c:/Users/ely/Documents/Desarrollo/Spring/springsource/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.1.v20140709-1414.jar, file:c:/Users/ely/Documents/Desarrollo/Spring/springsource/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/plugins/org.eclipse.fx.osgi_1.2.0.201501301028.jar
osgi.install.area=file:/C:/Users/ely/Documents/Desarrollo/Spring/springsource/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1/sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/
osgi.instance.area=file:/C:/Users/ely/Documents/Desarrollo/Spring/workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE/
osgi.instance.area.default=file:/C:/Users/ely/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.4.RELEASE/
osgi.logfile=C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\.metadata\.log
osgi.nl=en_US
osgi.os=win32
osgi.splashLocation=c:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher\org.springsource.sts_3.6.4.201503100339-RELEASE\splash.bmp
osgi.splashPath=platform:/base/plugins/org.springsource.sts
osgi.syspath=c:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\plugins
osgi.tracefile=C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\.metadata\trace.log
osgi.user.area=file:/C:/Users/ely/user/
osgi.ws=win32
path.separator=;
sun.arch.data.model=64
sun.boot.class.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\classes
sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\bin
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.cpu.isalist=amd64
sun.desktop=windows
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.java.command=C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\STS.exe -name STS --launcher.library C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316\eclipse_1608.dll -startup C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar --launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata 2854_5c -product org.springsource.sts.ide -data C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\workspace-sts-3.6.3.RELEASE -vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/javaw.exe -vmargs -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
sun.java.launcher=SUN_STANDARD
sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252
sun.management.compiler=HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
sun.os.patch.level=Service Pack 1
user.country=US
user.country.format=MX
user.dir=C:\Users\ely\Documents\Desarrollo\Spring\springsource\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE-e4.4.1\sts-3.6.3.RELEASE
user.home=C:\Users\ely
user.language=en
user.language.format=es
user.name=ely
user.script=
user.timezone=America/Mexico_City
user.variant=

*** Features:
com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.jira (3.2.3.v20140630) "Atlassian Connector for Eclipse Branding"
com.atlassian.connector.eclipse.monitor (3.2.3.v20140630) "Atlassian Connector for Eclipse Branding"
org.aspectj (1.8.5.20150128171000) "AspectJ Development Tools"
org.cloudfoundry.ide.eclipse.server (1.8.1.201503242338-RELEASE) "Cloud Foundry Integration for Eclipse"
org.eclipse.ajdt (2.2.4.e44x-20150202-1700) "AspectJ Development Tools"
org.eclipse.cvs (1.4.100.v20150204-1700) "Eclipse CVS Client"
org.eclipse.datatools.common.doc.user (1.12.0.v201405281819-26-311A16321A3557) "Data Tools Platform User Documentation"
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.doc.user (1.12.0.v201405281819-37D-7733L3D753L7BBF) "Data Tools Platform Connectivity User Documentation"
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.feature (1.12.0.v201406061321-7C7n9DEsxcwtN5odeWrQrgwYHq8) "Data Tools Platform Connectivity Plug-in"
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.designer.core.feature (1.12.0.v201406061321-787B7PBgJ9DUBNCVAaSZ) "DTP ODA Designer UI Framework Plug-in"
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.designer.feature (1.12.0.v201406061321-4147w312514242925) "DTP ODA Designer UI Framework Plug-in"
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.feature (1.12.0.v201406061321-7E7C7YBgJ9ET9OHLDfLZ) "DTP Open Data Access"
org.eclipse.datatools.doc.user (1.12.0.v201405281819-47C18w95FHAM87EJJD7) "Data Tool Platform User Documentation"
org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.apache.derby.feature (1.12.0.v201406061321-777B8gBmKFQ3NjRaMjbx8GDI) "High-level Sybase Enablement Plug-in"
...
```

Here is my pom:

```
...    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.SisIntAdminBackendApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>

        <postgresql.version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</postgresql.version>
        <querydsl.version>3.6.0</querydsl.version>
        <querydsl.apt-maven-plugin.version>1.1.3</querydsl.apt-maven-plugin.version>
        <querydsl.generated.src>target/generated-sources/queries</querydsl.generated.src>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QUERYDSL Inicio -->
        <!-- http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.4.2/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e123 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${querydsl.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- QUERYDSL Fin -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cz.jirutka.rsql</groupId>
            <artifactId>rsql-parser</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- Procesar Códigos de barras Bidimensionales (QR) -->
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- Procesar Códigos de barras Bidimensionales (QR) -->
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Para descarga de XML's desde el SAT (realiza conexinoes get y post, algo similar a curl) -->
            <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ http://jsoup.org/ -->
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <!-- QUERYDSL Inicio -->
                <!-- http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/3.4.2/reference/html/ch02.html#d0e123 -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${querydsl.apt-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${querydsl.generated.src}</outputDirectory>
                                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

                <!-- QUERYDSL Fin -->

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>XsdCfdi</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsds</schemaDirectory>
                                <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xsds</bindingDirectory>
                                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/xml/extracted</generateDirectory>
                                <generatePackage>mx.i4b.sisintadmin.xml.schemas.extraced</generatePackage>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>WebServiceSATConsultaQR</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generate</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                                <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/sat/extracted/consultaCfdiWebService</generateDirectory>
                                <generatePackage>mx.i4b.sisintadmin.util.sat.extracted.consultaCfdiWebService</generatePackage>
                                <schemas>
                                    <schema>
                                        <url>https://consultaqr.facturaelectronica.sat.gob.mx/ConsultaCFDIService.svc?wsdl</url>
                                    </schema>
                                </schemas>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <!-- QUERYDSL Inicio -->
            <!-- http://stackoverflow.com/a/10755824/2796922: "without the <pluginManagement> 
                level betweeen <build> and <plugins>" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- QUERYDSL Fin -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.12.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: First have you tried to build on console only **not** inside eclipse? Which Maven version do you use? Which Eclipse version and m2e version do you use?

Comment: Also, maybe post your pom.xml. It will surely help people to help you.

Comment: @khmarbaise How do I build on console?... it didn't recognize the `mvn build` command and `mvn compile` worked just fine, but didn't create the queryDsl classes. Then I did it again through eclipse: got the same error message, but did create the queryDsl classes.

Comment: @khmarbaise. I tried to add all the used versions in my post... how do I obtain the ones you are asking me for?

Comment: @JFPicard Done. Added the pom. (Had to remove some of my previous "configuration" lines in order to make space for the pom.)